# Ensure order in for loop involving json_decode()

Tags: php, json, implode

I'm using `json_decode` to parse JSON files.  In a for loop, I attempt to capture specific cases in the JSON in which one element or another exist.  I've implemented a function that seems to fit my needs, but I find that I need to use two for loops to get it to catch both of my cases.

I would rather use a single loop, if that's possible, but I'm stuck on how to get both cases caught in a single pass.  Here's a mockup of what I would like the result to look like:

```
<?php
function extract($thisfile){
    $test = implode("", file($thisfile));
    $obj = json_decode($test, true);

    for ($i = 0; $i <= sizeof($obj['patcher']['boxes']); $i ++) {
        //this is sometimes found 2nd
        if ($obj['patcher']['boxes'][$i]['box']['name'] == "mystring1") {
        }

        //this is sometimes found 1st
        if ($obj['patcher']['boxes'][$i]['box']['name'] == "mystring2") {
        }
    }    
}
?>
```

Can anyone tell me how I could catch both cases outlined above within a single iteration?
I clearly could not do something like

```
if ($obj['patcher']['boxes'][$i]['box']['name'] == "string1" && $obj['patcher']['boxes'][$i]['box']['name'] == "string2") {}
```

...because that condition would never be met.

Comment: But you *are* using only a single loop/pass... also, the `file`/`implode` is unnecessary: just use `file_get_contents`.

Comment: I'm only using a single pass in my example to clarify what I would like the result to look like.

Comment: what you've written, does that not work?

Comment: no, check out the comments `//` I made in that code regarding the problems.  Sometimes one selector is found, and sometimes another.

Comment: @jml: It's not clear what you are asking. You want to stop only when both values are found, but you are not sure in what order you will encounter them? That doesn't sound too complicated; in essence you simply want two flags and a custom exit condition: `if ($found1 && $found2) break;`.

Comment: I am not sure what order I _will_ encounter them, because I did not write the files that are passed into my function.  I need two separate blocks of code to execute based on one or the other being found.  Would you use two separate for loops?

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a bit confused. To understand this... you have a json decoded tree/structure/obj that you're looping through and you're checking the `$obj['patcher']['boxes'][$i]['box']['name']` to see if it is `"mystring1"` or `"mystring2"`. And based on those conditions you evaluate your other pieces of code. But you want to control the order that they are found? For instance, you want to catch all the `"mystring1"` first then `"mystring2"`?

Comment: @Aesphere Yes, precisely.

Comment: I don't think you can get around having another loop unless you find a way to reorder the data but that would complicate things beyond needed. What you could do is store the indexes of the second condition in an array and loop through that so that your second loop isn't as long. Or you could do it for both conditions etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that something like what @Jon had mentioned is probably the best way to attack this problem, for me at least:

```
<?php
function extract($thisfile){
    $test = implode("", file($thisfile));
    $obj = json_decode($test, true);
    $found1 = $found2 = false;

    for ($i = 0; $i <= sizeof($obj['patcher']['boxes']); $i ++) {
        //this is sometimes found 2nd
        if ($obj['patcher']['boxes'][$i]['box']['name'] == "mystring1") {
            $found1 = true;
        }

        //this is sometimes found 1st
        if ($obj['patcher']['boxes'][$i]['box']['name'] == "mystring2") {
            $found2 = true;
        }

        if ($found1 && $found2){ 
            break;
        }
    }    

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally what I do when I have raw data that is in an order that isn't ideal to work with is to run a first loop pass to generate a a list of indexes for me to pass through a second time.
So a quick example from your code:

```
<?php
function extract($thisfile){
    $test = implode("", file($thisfile));
    $obj = json_decode($test, true);

    $index_mystring2 = array(); //Your list of indexes for the second condition

    //1st loop.
    $box_name;
    for ($i = 0; $i <= sizeof($obj['patcher']['boxes']); $i ++) {
        $box_name = $obj['patcher']['boxes'][$i]['box']['name'];

        if ( $box_name == "mystring1") {
             //Do your code here for condition 1
        }

        if ($box_name == "mystring2") {
           //We push the index onto an array for a later loop.
           array_push($index_mystring2, $i); 
        }
    }

    //2nd loop
    for($j=0; $j<=sizeof($index_mystring2); $j++) {
      //Your code here. do note that $obj['patcher']['boxes'][$j]
      // will refer you to the data in your decoded json tree
    }
}
?>
```

Granted you can do this in more generic ways so it's cleaner (ie, generate both the first and second conditions into indexes) but i think you get the idea :)

Comment: I think what I am looking for is more in line with what @Jon was alluding to.

Comment: I guess I'm lacking info. Are you trying the track the order of the conditions that you find? for instance, say you found mystring1 first, then mystring2 afterwards. Then based on that result, mystring2 after mystring1, you run a piece of code. If mystring2 was found before mystring1, you'd run a different piece of code?